# React: set the state based on array values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of questions like this

```
[
  {
    title: 'what_are_your_hobbies',
  },
  {
    title: 'do_you_know_german',
  },
]
```

how can I iterate over this array and set its titles to the state like:

```
state = {
  what_are_your_hobbies: '',
  do_you_know_german: ''
}
```

Comment: do you always want to set empty string as value?

Comment: mostly, sometimes I'd like to set some to arrays, but I can do it with setState and add values. Is that a problem if I set it to an empty string first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array and set all `title` to a key on the new object and use that to update your state.

**Example**

```
const arr = [
  {
    title: "what_are_your_hobbies"
  },
  {
    title: "do_you_know_german"
  }
];
const stateUpdate = arr.reduce((result, element) => {
  result[element.title] = "";
  return result;
}, {});

this.setState(stateUpdate);
```

Comment: @SungKim Thanks Sung! Glad to hear it.